Characterising maximal ideals in polynomial rings over Noetherian rings.
Let $R[\vec{x}]=R[x_1,x_2,...,x_n]$ be a polynomial ring over a UFD with the Noetherian property. The following is an attempt to characterise its maximal ideals.
Since $R$ is Noetherian and a UFD, then so is $R[\vec{x}]$. Since $R[\vec{x}]$ is Noetherian, it is finitely generated; so, for every ideal $I\subset R[\vec{x}]$, there must be a finite generating subset $\mathrm{Gen}(I)\subseteq R[\vec{x}]$ with $\mathrm{Gen}(I)=\{f_1,...,f_n\}$ such that:
$$I=\{\sum_iq_if_i\in R[\vec{x}]|q_i\in R[\vec{x}]\}=\sum_i⟨f_i⟩$$
Let $\{p_{ij},u_i\}\subseteq R[\vec{x}]$, $p_{ij}$ prime elements, $u_i$ units, have the prime factorisation:
$$f_i=u_i\prod_jp_{ij}^{\alpha_{ij}}$$
We then have
$$⟨f_i⟩=\bigcap_j⟨p_{ij}^{\alpha_{ij}}⟩$$
And hence:
$$I=\sum_i⟨f_i⟩=\sum_i\left(\bigcap_j⟨p_{ij}^{\alpha_{ij}}⟩\right)$$
Finally, for every pair of ideals $\{N_i,M_i\}\subseteq 2^{R[\vec{x}]}$ we have $\sqrt{N_i\cap M_i}=\sqrt{N_i}\cap \sqrt{M_i}$, and $N_i\subseteq M_i\Rightarrow \sum_iN_i\subseteq \sum_iM_i$ so, by set-theoretical considerations, it can be shown that there's an ideal $J\supseteq I$ that satisfies
$$J=\sum_i\left(\bigcap_j\sqrt{⟨p_{ij}^{\alpha_{ij}}⟩}\right)=\sum_i\left(\bigcap_j⟨p_{ij}⟩\right)$$
And also a class of ideals $M_j$ that show $I\subseteq J\subseteq M_j$, with
$$M_j=\sum_i⟨p_{ij}⟩$$
Where $⟨p_{ij}⟩$ is prime (and hence, irreducible in every UFD) for any given $j$. Since $I$ was chosen arbitrarily, it can be chosen to be maximal; but then $I=M_j\subset R[\vec{x}]$, and hence, every maximal ideal of $R[\vec{x}]$ is a sum of irreducible ideals.
I believe this proof is correct, but the fact that, in the last step, $M_j$ can be substituted with $J$ to show that every maximal ideal can be written as a sum of ideal intersections (the class of ideal intersections contains reducible ideals) bugs me. Must i refine this proof further?

Note that $R[\vec{x}]$ is Noetherian only if $R$ itself is Noetherian. A UFD need not be Noetherian, so it sounds like you probably want to add that hypothesis?

I think the main problem of the proof is that it relies on the hypothesis of $M_j$ being maximal, without explicitly showing it must not be contained in any set... But the class of sums of irreducible ideals surely contains every maximal ideal (by these considerations).
